# Laravel 4 Route Filter Never Called

Tags: filter, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am sure that I am doing something wrong that is very obvious, but for some reason I cannot get any filters except App::before to work in my test application.

//routes.php

```
Route::get('site/login',
               array(
                    'before'=>'science',
                    'as'=>'site/login',
                    'uses'=>'HomeController@getLogin',
               )
           );
Route::controller(site, 'HomeController');
```

//filters.php

```
App::before(function($request){
    //var_dump("Before"); exit;
});

Route::filter('science',function(){
   dd("Science B!TCH!");
   exit;
});
```

//HomeController.php

```
public function getLogin(){
    $this->layout->body = View::make('home.login');
}
```

The object was first to ensure that a user was not logged in so I was trying to use the built-in "guest" filter, but it was never being called.  So I later created the "science" filter to test if ANY routes would work. If I uncomment the var_dump line in App::before, it displays "Before" and exits as expected.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?  When I go to the /site/login page I should see my Breaking Bad movie quote instead of the actual page.  However, I am seeing my login form as if nothing was happening.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I changed the route to look like this now:

//routes.php

```
Route::get('site/login', 'HomeController@getLogin')->before('science');
```

... and it works.  I get the debugging string "SCIENCE ..." on the screen.

It also works if I do the following

//HomeController.php

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->beforeFilter('science');
}
```

Are there any use cases or conditions in which the array version of routes gets ignored?

UPDATE 2:
In my efforts to simplify my original description I neglected to show other routes that were in routes.php.  Take a look below.

//routes.php

```
Route::get('site/login',
                    array(
                        'before'=>'science',
                        'as'=>'site/login',
                        'uses'=>'HomeController@getLogin'
                    )
                );
Route::post('site/login',
               array(
                    'as'=>'site/login',
                    'uses'=>'HomeController@postLogin'
               )
);
```

Having the POST route AFTER the GET route is what is causing the problem.  When I put the POST route BEFORE the GET route, the GET route works with the filter as expected.

Now, I was under the impression that Laravel treated GET and POST requests differently, hence the usage of the different static methods in Route.  However, apparently, this is not true as the filter on the latter affects the filter of the former.

Is this a correct assumption? Should I start a different thread about this?  I would love to understand why this is working this way.

Thanks!

UPDATE 3

---- SOLVED ---

This tidbit of information is not specifically stated in the documentation but you **cannot have identical route names even though those route names are going to different REST verbs.**

//routes.php BEFORE

```
Route::get('site/login',  array('as'=>'site/login','uses'=>'HomeController@getLogin', 'before'=>'science'));
Route::post('site/login', array('as'=>'site/login', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postLogin',));
```

In the above solution, the 2nd Route OVERRIDES the previous route because the "as" uses the same name.  I thought that these would be treated differently since one is GET and the other POST, but this is not the case.  The filter assignments must happen by name in the backend and, as such, using identical names will override each other.

//routes.php AFTER

```
Route::get('site/login',  array('as'=>'site/login','uses'=>'HomeController@getLogin', 'before'=>'science'));
Route::post('site/login', array('as'=>'site/postLogin', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postLogin',));
```

As you can see here, I renamed the 'as' part of the array to 'site/postLogin' and I can now use different filters for each the POST, GET, and probably PUT, DELETE and etc.

Comment: Have you modified any other files? What modifications have you done to the start folder etc? I tried your code and it worked for me.

Comment: I know it's strange, I haven't made any changes to the start folder or any other core files.  Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: I assume you're just trying out Laravel with this sort of project, push it to a github repo and I'll try out your exact copy tonight?

Comment: I updated the description with some more information.  I can get it to work as long as I don't use the array to specify the route parameters. I am trying out Laravel, but I am unsure what I can post on Github thanks to the NDA I signed in this project.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using, the beta? I assume not so this is quite weird.. As a side note, use `return View::make('view');` instead of setting the attribute directly.

Comment: I updated the question with more information. Using Laravel 4

Comment: It has been a long time since this question, but I think that I know what was causing it.  I had a similar problem recently that had to do with the TRAILING SLASH.  If your application is routing to a POST/PATCH/PUT with a TRAILING SLASH, Laravel will do a 301 redirect (Thanks?) which makes it look like a GET request.  This is probably why when you have a different route name the problem goes away as the 301 redirect figures it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---- SOLVED ---

This tidbit of information is not specifically stated in the documentation but you **cannot have identical route names even though those route names are going to different REST verbs.**

//routes.php BEFORE

```
Route::get('site/login',  array('as'=>'site/login','uses'=>'HomeController@getLogin', 'before'=>'science'));
Route::post('site/login', array('as'=>'site/login', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postLogin',));
```

In the above solution, the 2nd Route OVERRIDES the previous route because the "as" uses the same name.  I thought that these would be treated differently since one is GET and the other POST, but this is not the case.  The filter assignments must happen by name in the backend and, as such, using identical names will override each other.

//routes.php AFTER

```
Route::get('site/login',  array('as'=>'site/login','uses'=>'HomeController@getLogin', 'before'=>'science'));
Route::post('site/login', array('as'=>'site/postLogin', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postLogin',));
```

As you can see here, I renamed the 'as' part of the array to 'site/postLogin' and I can now use different filters for each the POST, GET, and probably PUT, DELETE and etc.

Answer (score 1):

For better practice if two or more routes use the same filter, those routes should belong in a group. I have a feeling that will correct the issue.

From http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        // Has Auth Filter
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function()
    {
        // Has Auth Filter
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks fruityp, but I found out the problem.  I was using identical route names in the 'as' array field and this was causing the latter to override the former.  I appreciate all your help!  I just wish the documentation would explain this!

Comment: No worries, send a pull request :)